# Using socket.io and node.js, button click does not trigger event

Tags: node.js, socket.io, buttonclick, no-response

On button click, the message 'door' should appear on the console but it isn't.

Client code :

```
<button type="button" onClick = "doorClicked()">Door</button>

function doorClicked(){
        socket.emit('door', function(data){
            socket.send("Door");
        });
}

Server side :
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('door', function(data){
        console.log('Door');
    });
}
```

Comment: On the client, don't pass a function - instead pass the payload. You don't need to call send.

Comment: just passing the payload will require changes on the server-side as well, and when I changed the server-side code as follows :                    socket.on('door', 
 io.sockets.emit('doorEvent', {msg: data})
);                                                                                                                      I got the following error : Reference Error : Data is not defined                      ...Tried searching for a sloution for the same, but no luck @tariksbl

Answer (score 0):

You should try this on doorClicked function:

```
function doorClicked(){
    socket.emit('door');}
```

You don't need any data to emit. Because you are consoling out the string 'Door'.
So, your server side code should be like this,

```
    Server side :
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('door', function(){
        console.log('Door');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is solved and it was in the part of the code which I haven't mentioned in my question, and I'm extremely sorry for that.

On the client-side code, I had the button along with other button in the same form, and whenever I clicked the other button, the event was notified. So I tried placing the buttons on different  tags in my client-side HTML code and it worked fine.

P.S. I didn't include the entire code earlier because I was expecting the error to be in the part of the code that had to deal with socket.io since I was new at it.